# Spotify Dataset: How to query the MAX (highest played track) and the MIN (lowest played track) from the SUM (total stream per track) per Artist?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm new to SQL. It has been challenging so far but I feel cool learning about it :D

I'm presented with this Spotify data set and is tasked to query Artist A and B's least and highest played songs.

| Date | Artist | Track | Streams |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Date 1 | A | A1 | 2 |
| Date 1 | C | C1 | 3 |
| Date 2 | B | B1 | 5 |
| Date 2 | A | A1 | 4 |
| Date 3 | B | B2 | 5 |
| Date 4 | A | A2 | 1 |
| Date 4 | B | B1 | 2 |

How do I present my query like this?

| Artist | Highest Track Streamed | Lowest Track Streamed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | A1 with 6 streams | A2 with 1 stream |
| B | B1 with 7 streams | B2 with 5 streams |

**OR**

| Artist | Highest Track Name | Highest Track Streams | Lowest Track Name | Lowest Track Streams |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A1 | 6 | A2 | 1 |
| B | B1 | 7 | B2 | 5 |

Unfortunately, I'm stuck with this code:

I also discovered that you cannot "NEST" aggregate functions such as MAX and SUM in PostgresSQL...which sucks.

```
SELECT
  Artist,
  Track,
  MAX(SUM(Streams))AS Highest_Track_Streamed,
  MIN(SUM(Streams)) AS Lowest_Track_Streamed
FROM Spotify_Charts
WHERE Artist IN ('A', 'B')
GROUP BY Artist;
```

Answer (score 0):

- First find the sum of total streams per artist per track and store it in a cte.
- Then give a row number to the above result set based on the total streams in descending order per artist and store it in a different cte.
- Same as previous, but row number based on the ascending order of total streams.
- Lastly, join ctes from step 2 and step 3 based on matching artist and for only row number 1.

**Query**

```
with cte1 as (
  select artist, track, sum(stream) as total
  from your_table_name
  where artist in ('A','B')
  group by artist, track
),
cte2 as(
  select *, row_number() over (
    partition by artist
    order by total desc
  ) as mx
  from cte1
),
cte3 as(
  select *, row_number() over(
    partition by artist
    order by total
  ) as mn
  from cte1
)
select t1.artist, t1.track as highestTrackName,
t1.total as highestTrackStreams,
t2.track as lowestTrackName,
t2.total as lowestTrackStreams
from cte2 as t1
join cte3 as t2
on t1.artist = t2.artist
where t1.mx = 1 and t2.mn = 1;
```

[Find a demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/mpKhtRu6)

Comment: IT WORKED!!! But where did "t1" and "t2" came from?

Comment: t1 and t2 are the aliases used